# WrapDynaBeanをJSFで使用したい

Tags: java, java-ee, jsf

org.apache.commons.beanutils.WrapDynaBeanを継承したラッパーBeanでBeanをラップし、h:dataTableで表示したいです。

以下のコードではWrapperBeanからTestBeanのvalueを参照できないのでjavax.el.PropertyNotFoundExceptionが発生してしまいます。解決策はあるでしょうか？

**ラッパーBean**

```
public class WrapperBean extends WrapDynaBean{
    // テーブルのNo
    private int no;

    // setter, getter...
}
```

**ラップされるBean**

```
public class TestBean{
    private String value;

    // setter, getter...
}
```

**管理Bean**

```
public class TestController{

    private List<WrapperBean> wbList;

    @PostConstract
    private void init(){
        // テーブルの内容を保持したTestBeanをラップする。
        wbList.add(new WrapperBean(new TestBean("hoge"));
        wbList.add(new WrapperBean(new TestBean("huga"));
        wbList.add(new WrapperBean(new TestBean("piyo"));
    }
}
```

**test.xhtml**

```
<h:dataTable value="#{testController.wbList}" var="row"
    <h:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{row.no}"/>
    </h:column>

    <h:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{row.value}"/>
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 1):

test.xhtmlを下記のように書き換えれば出力されます。

```
<h:dataTable value="#{testController.wbList}" var="row">
    <h:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{row.no}"/>
    </h:column>

    <h:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{row.get('value')}"/>
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。getメソッドを使用するのではなく、プロパティ名で値を取得することはできないでしょうか？かつ、プロパティはプライベートなままで。

Comment: WrapDynaBeanクラスのコードを見るとわかりますが、ラップしたクラスに対するGetterを持っていない、またMapのサブクラスでもないためプロパティ名では取得できません。プロパティはプライベートのままというのはvalueプロパティのGetterをプライベートでということですか？

Comment: WrapperBeanをさらにラップしてもよいのであれば、‘org.apache.commons.beanutils.DynaBeanMapDecorator`でラップするという方法もあります。その場合、#{row.value}は取得できるようになりますが、#{row.no}が取得できなくなるという状態になります。

Comment: できるのであれば、私が質問に掲載している、test.xhtmlの記述のまま値を取得したいです。とりあえず、おしえてくださった‘org.apache.commons.beanutils.DynaBeanMapDecorator`を調べてみたいと思います。